# my Project Tango AR App Object movement with the color camera movement doesn't work properly

Tags: android, opengl-es, google-project-tango

I want to place a cube somewhere in the room. The cube is static in the room and always at the same point. At the moment I can place a cube in the room but if I move the Tango Tablet it isn't in sync with the movement of the cube and I don't know how to sync my Tango Tablet movement and object movement.

My thoughts were, if I move the Tango Tablet to the right my Cube moves to the left with same same "speed" as my Tango Tablet moves to the right. I tried this for all directions but as said before it is not very synced.

An other issue I have is, how can the cube be static if I point with the camera to an other direction and the device is at same position?

To be honest I started with OpenGL last week and I don't know all its function or if I do it the right way.

I hope you understand my problem and can give me some hints.

Here is the code I think is important to you to understand what I try to do:

GLSurfaceView Renderer Class:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    Quaternion q = new Quaternion(xr,yr,zr,wr);
    Vector3f vr = q.getEulerAngles();



    gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    //gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(vr.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(vr.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glRotatef(vr.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, z);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    mSquare.draw(gl);
}
```

Here is the code from MainActivity:

```
 private void startCameraPreview() {
    // Connect to color camera
    tangoCameraPreview.connectToTangoCamera(mTango,
            TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
    final ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair> framePairs = new ArrayList<TangoCoordinateFramePair>();

    framePairs.add(new TangoCoordinateFramePair(
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
            TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE));
    mTango.connectListener(framePairs, new Tango.OnTangoUpdateListener() {

@Override
        public void onPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose) {
            // We are not using OnPoseAvailable for this app
            tangoRenderer.getModelMatCalculator().updateModelMatrix(pose.getTranslationAsFloats(),pose.getRotationAsFloats());
            transolationData = pose.getTranslationAsFloats();
            data =  tangoRenderer.getModelMatCalculator().getTranslation();
            //transolationData = tangoRenderer.getModelMatCalculator().getTranslation();

            Quaternion q = new Quaternion((float)pose.rotation[0],(float)pose.rotation[1],(float)pose.rotation[2],(float)pose.rotation[3]);
            final Vector3f vr = q.getEulerAngles();


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (transolationData != null) {
                        pose_text_view.setText("BU X: " + Math.round(transolationData[0] * 100f) / 100f + " Z: " + Math.round(transolationData[1] * 100f) / 100f + " Y: " + Math.round(transolationData[2] * 100f) / 100f + " length from transolationData: " + transolationData.length + "\n");
                        pose_text_winkel.setText("Winkel X: " + decimalFormat.format((vr.x*100)/100) + " Y: " + decimalFormat.format((vr.y*100)/100) + " Z: " +  decimalFormat.format((vr.z*100)/100) + "\n"
                        + "Device Daten X: " + decimalFormat.format(data[0]) + " Y: " + decimalFormat.format(data[1]) + " Z: " + decimalFormat.format(data[2]));

                        // + " CameraView X: " + tangoCameraPreview.getTranslationX() + " Y: " + tangoCameraPreview.getTranslationY()  + " Z: " + tangoCameraPreview.getTranslationZ());
                    }
                }
            });


            if(isCubeSet){



              /*  neuX = (data[0]+x);
                neuY = (data[1]+y);
                neuZ = -(data[2]+z);*/

                neuX = (transolationData[0]+x);
                neuY = (transolationData[2]+y);
                neuZ = -(data[2]+z);

                rendererCube.setX(neuX);
                rendererCube.setY(neuY);
                rendererCube.setZ(neuZ);

                rendererCube.setXr((float) pose.rotation[0]);
                rendererCube.setYr((float) pose.rotation[1]);
                rendererCube.setZr((float) pose.rotation[2]);
                rendererCube.setWr((float) pose.rotation[3]);

            }
        }
```

Here i set my cube with start points:

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(!isCubeSet){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            x = data[0];
            y = data[1];
            z  = -data[2];

            neuX = x;
            neuY = y;
            neuZ = z;

            rendererCube.setX(x);
            rendererCube.setY(y);
            rendererCube.setZ(z);
            isCubeSet = true;
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            isCubeSet = false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Every time I see deprecated API all my motivation to help drops to zero. :/

Comment: I Can't see any deprecated API or Android Studio doens't show which API is deprecated

Comment: You're right.Android Studio doesn't.But OpenGL does.And you are using GLES1.1 which uses deprecated API.

Comment: So i have to change it to opengl 2.0 and than maybe some of my problems would be easier to fix?

Comment: I suggest you to learn OpenGL API first.OpenGL is not kind of stuff which works out of the box if you have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: Ok then i learn OpenGl first, but would you say my problem is opengl? If not it would be great if someone could tell which kind of data i should use from the tango tablet

Comment: based on your code I can't tell you what's your problem because it is not pure OpenGL code and I don't have Android studio setup.If you are new to OpenGL,try for the starter to implement it in Android SDK independent environment.You have openGL ES desktop emulators(by PowerVR) for this.Then you will be able to see where is your issue.

Comment: Do you have any suggeston which books i should read and which opengl version for mobile Devices?